# How to stop the delay in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, command-line

So I'm trying to make an Ascii Video Player in Python, and it works but it's very slow. Is there any way that I can stop the delay, and also I can't see the top of the frame.

```
import os
import sys
import cv2
from PIL import Image

Chars = ["@", "#", "S", "%", "?", "*", "+", ";", ":", ",", "."]

def resized_gray_image(image, new_width=140):
    width, height = image.size
    aspectRatio = height/width
    newHeight = int(aspectRatio * new_width)
    resized_gray_image= image.resize((new_width, newHeight)).convert('L')
    return resized_gray_image

def pix2char(image):
    pixels = image.getdata()
    characters = "".join([Chars[pixel//25] for pixel in pixels])
    return characters

def show_image(image, new_width=140):
    new_image_data = pix2char(resized_gray_image(image))

    totalPixels = len(new_image_data)
    ascii_image = "\n".join([new_image_data[index:(index+new_width)] for index in range(0, totalPixels, new_width)])

    sys.stdout.write(ascii_image)
    os.system('cls')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("BadApple.mp4")

while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    show_image(Image.fromarray(frame))
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `range()` function does not include the upper limit due to which upper limit of you images is not being added. You can include the upper limit by.

```
ascii_image = "\n".join([new_image_data[index:(index+new_width)] if new_width < totalPixels else new_image_data[index:totalPixels] for index in range(0, totalPixels, new_width)])
```

To improve the speed you can run the `show_image` function in a thread.

```
from threading Thread

while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    Thread(target=show_image, args=(Image.fromarray(frame), ), daemon=True).start()
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Yeah, but I'm now getting the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Python Files\BadAPPPLE.py", line 34, in <module>
    Thread(target=show_image, args=(Image.fromarray(frame), ), daemon=True).start()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2943, in fromarray
    arr = obj.__array_interface__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'

Comment: try for saving the image in a variable and then give it in args. For example.

`img = Image.fromarray(frame)`

`Thread(target=show_image, args=(img, ), daemon=True).start()`